# How to efficiently test some HTTP proxies for accessing a specific domain?

Tags: python, asynchronous, proxy, aiohttp, httpx

I need an efficient way to test some free online HTTP proxies and determine which ones can access a specific website;

And since that proxy testing involves significant waiting time, I opted to redesign my code for asynchronous testing. I then explored the httpx and aiohttp packages. However, I encountered unexpected behaviors, leading me to question if my current code is the best fit for my purpose.

Below is the output of the code for three methods I used:

- one using the requests package for synchronous testing,
- and the other two for asynchronous testing.

As you can see, there are several errors, and the time taken to complete each request varies significantly.
Interestingly, the ***requests method*** returned an HTTP 200 status for four links, while the ***httpx method*** returned five, and the ***aiohttp method*** returned nothing, which is unexpected considering they are supposed to perform the same task. This raises doubts about how I implemented them.

Additionally, in the ***httpx method***, one proxy took an inexplicably long time, even though I set the timeout to 60 seconds. It took 13,480.64 seconds (I should mention that during this test, I put my PC into sleep mode when I noticed it was taking too long. When I returned later, I found that the process hadn't stopped and was still running.)

### Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here and how I could improve it?

```
 1) --> 185.XXX.XX.XX:80     --> ProxyError      (4.96s)
 2) --> 38.XX.XXX.XXX:443    --> HTTP (200)      (2.50s)
 3) --> 162.XXX.XX.XXX:80    --> HTTP (200)      (20.92s)
 4) --> 18.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080  --> HTTP (200)      (0.61s)
 5) --> 31.XX.XX.XX:50687    --> ConnectionError (7.88s)
 6) --> 177.XX.XXX.XXX:80    --> ProxyError      (21.07s)
 7) --> 8.XXX.XXX.X:4153     --> HTTP (200)      (4.96s)
 8) --> 146.XX.XXX.XXX:12334 --> ProxyError      (21.05s)
 9) --> 67.XX.XXX.XXX:33081  --> ProxyError      (3.03s)
10) --> 37.XXX.XX.XX:80      --> ReadTimeout     (60.16s)
Testing 10 proxies with "requests" took 147.16 seconds.


 4) --> 18.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080  --> HTTP (200)          (16.09s)
 2) --> 38.XX.XXX.XXX:443    --> HTTP (200)          (22.11s)
 7) --> 8.XXX.XXX.X:4153     --> HTTP (200)          (12.96s)
 1) --> 185.XXX.XX.XX:80     --> RemoteProtocolError (24.83s)
 9) --> 67.XX.XXX.XXX:33081  --> ConnectError        (6.02s)
 3) --> 162.XXX.XX.XXX:80    --> HTTP (200)          (22.48s)
 6) --> 177.XX.XXX.XXX:80    --> HTTP (200)          (26.96s)
 5) --> 31.XX.XX.XX:50687    --> ConnectError        (34.50s)
 8) --> 146.XX.XXX.XXX:12334 --> ConnectError        (27.01s)
10) --> 37.XXX.XX.XX:80      --> ReadError           (13480.64s)
Testing 10 proxies with "httpx" took 13507.80 seconds.


 1) --> 185.XXX.XX.XX:80     --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (1.30s)
 2) --> 38.XX.XXX.XXX:443    --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (0.67s)
 3) --> 162.XXX.XX.XXX:80    --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (0.77s)
 4) --> 18.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080  --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (0.83s)
 5) --> 31.XX.XX.XX:50687    --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (0.85s)
 6) --> 177.XX.XXX.XXX:80    --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (0.91s)
 7) --> 8.XXX.XXX.X:4153     --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (0.94s)
 8) --> 146.XX.XXX.XXX:12334 --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (1.03s)
 9) --> 67.XX.XXX.XXX:33081  --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (1.05s)
10) --> 37.XXX.XX.XX:80      --> ClientProxyConnectionError  (0.62s)
Testing 10 proxies with "aiohttp" took 2.42 seconds.
```

Here's the code I used:

I started by downloading the proxies from [this](https://github.com/TheSpeedX/PROXY-List?tab=readme-ov-file#proxy-list) GitHub repository:

```python
import random
import tempfile
import os
import requests
import time
import asyncio
import httpx
import aiohttp

TIMEOUT: int = 60
DEFAULT_DOMAIN: str = r"www.desired.domain.com"
PROXIES_URL: str = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSpeedX/SOCKS-List/master/http.txt"
PROXIES_PATH: str = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "httpProxies.txt")
HEADERS: dict = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "accept-language": "en,ar;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "dnt": "1",
    "referer": "https://www.google.com/",
    "sec-ch-ua": '"Microsoft Edge";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"',
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/123.0.0.0",
    "Connection": "close",  # "keep-alive",
}

def get_proxies() -> list[str]:
    proxies: list[str] = []
    if os.path.exists(PROXIES_PATH):
        with open(file=PROXIES_PATH, mode="r") as file:
            proxies = file.read().splitlines()
            file.close()
    else:
        response = requests.request(method="GET", url=PROXIES_URL)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            proxies = response.text
            with open(file=PROXIES_PATH, mode="w") as file:
                file.write(proxies)
                file.close()
            proxies = proxies.split("\n")
    return proxies
```

below is the method I used to sequentially test those proxies:

```python
def sequential_test(proxies_list: list[str]):
    if proxies_list:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            session.headers = HEADERS
            for i, proxy in enumerate(proxies_list, 1):
                session.proxies = {"http": f"http://{proxy}"}
                try:
                    color = "\033[91m"
                    start = time.perf_counter()
                    response = session.get(url=f"http://{DEFAULT_DOMAIN}", timeout=TIMEOUT)
                    status = f"HTTP ({response.status_code})"
                    if response.status_code == 200:
                        color = "\033[92m"
                except Exception as exception:  # requests.RequestException
                    status = type(exception).__name__
                print(f"{i:>2}) --> {color+proxy:30}\033[0m --> {status:20}\t({time.perf_counter()-start:.2f}s)")
```

The following is the code I used to test if a proxy is working with the desired website or not. I employed httpx and aiohttp, respectively:

```python
async def is_alive_httpx(index: int, proxy: str, domain: str = DEFAULT_DOMAIN) -> None:
    proxy_mounts = {"http://": httpx.AsyncHTTPTransport(proxy=f"http://{proxy}"),}
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(
        mounts=proxy_mounts,
        timeout=TIMEOUT,
        headers=HEADERS,
        follow_redirects=True
    ) as session:
        try:
            color = "\033[91m"
            start = time.perf_counter()
            response = await session.send(httpx.Request(method="GET", url=f"http://{domain}"))
            status = f"HTTP ({response.status_code})"
            if response.status_code == 200:
                color = "\033[92m"
        except Exception as exception:  # httpx.HTTPError
            status = type(exception).__name__
        print(f"{index:>2}) --> {color+proxy:30}\033[0m --> {status:20}\t({time.perf_counter()-start:.2f}s)"
```

```python
async def is_alive_aiohttp(index: int, proxy: str, domain: str = DEFAULT_DOMAIN) -> None:
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=TIMEOUT), headers=HEADERS, trust_env=True,
                                         connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl_context=None, force_close=True, limit_per_host=5)) as client:
            color = "\033[91m"
            start = time.perf_counter()
            response = await client.get(url=f"http://{domain}", proxy=f"http://{proxy}")
            status = f"HTTP ({response.status})"
            if response.status == 200:
                color = "\033[92m"
    except Exception as exception:  # aiohttp.ClientError
        status = type(exception).__name__
        print(status + ":", exception)
    finally:
        await client.close()
    print(f"{index:>2}) --> {color+proxy:30}\033[0m --> {status:26}\t({time.perf_counter()-start:.2f}s)")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
```

Below is the remainder of the code. You can run it directly by copying it into your environment, (just ensure you have the required packages installed):

```python
async def test_proxies(proxies_list: list[str], func):
    if proxies_list:
        await asyncio.gather(*[func(ip[0], ip[1]) for ip in enumerate(proxies_list, 1)])


def main():
    proxies = random.sample(get_proxies(), 10)  # get_proxies()[:10]

    start = time.perf_counter()
    sequential_test(proxies)
    print(f'\nTesting {len(proxies)} proxies with "requests" took {time.perf_counter()-start:.2f} seconds.\n')

    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(test_proxies(proxies, is_alive_httpx))
    print(f'\nTesting {len(proxies)} proxies with "httpx" took {time.perf_counter()-start:.2f} seconds.\n')

    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(test_proxies(proxies, is_alive_aiohttp))
    print(f'\nTesting {len(proxies)} proxies with "aiohttp" took {time.perf_counter()-start:.2f} seconds.\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are some of the errors I frequently encounter when using ***aiohttp***, for example:

- **ClientProxyConnectionError**: Cannot connect to host ssl:default

  - [The semaphore timeout period has expired]
  - [The remote computer refused the network connection]
- **ClientResponse**:

  - [409 Conflict]
  - [407 Proxy Authentication Required]
- **ClientOSError**:

  - [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
  - [WinError 1236] The network connection was aborted by the local system
- **ServerDisconnectedError**: Server disconnected.

Comment: **I want to scrape a website without facing rate limitations.** Why? Those rate limits are there for a reason.

Comment: Why not? I believed that providing some context wouldn't be harmful to anyone. Isn't my question clear? I thought I was asking about how to efficiently test multiple proxies, not how to scrape. @Barmar

Comment: No, you're trying to get around the site's rate limits. It seems wrong to me.

Comment: Have you considered a simple multithreaded approach with *requests*

Comment: Yeah, I've considered that, but I prefer to initially focus on optimizing what a single thread can achieve. After that, I can implement multithreading functionality. @SIGHUP

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose the error from your aiohttp code, it's important to print the full exception details, not just its name.

```py
print(exception)
```

In this code, detailed information is printed about what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I didn't even think to examine the meaning of each error, as I wasn't entirely confident if the code I wrote was the correct way to test proxies. Do you have any other suggestions? Your input is welcome.